# cassandra upgrade problems 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, conflict

I am pretty new to cassandra so apologies if this is already covered.

On CentOS7, I am trying to upgrade to 2.1 (from 2.0) however after running
    `yum remove dsc2.0`
when I run
    `yum install dsc21`

I get multiple errors in the form of:

`Transaction check error:`
    `file /etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra from install of cassandra21-2.1.2-1.noarch conflicts with file from package cassandra20-2.0.12-1.noarch`
`...... (many more such conflicts)`

What am I forgetting? or is it safe to just delete each and every file reported to be conflicting?

Thanks,
Serhan.

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue on centos7.  I think it has to be a bug (I'm upgrading from 2.0.9 to 2.1) I am trying to file a bug report. I'll post it here once I have done so. EDIT: upon researching, it looks as though here is the best place for the issue to live. I get the same behavior as you and I have attempted the upgrade on two separate fresh systems both returning the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

You would also need to run:

```
yum remove cassandra20
```

before installing dsc21